# Правильно ли говорить "подписывается как" в смысле "называется"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, семантика, жаргон, компьютеры

Правильно ли говорить "подписывается как" в смысле "называется"?

Контекст — цифровой профиль (в компьютерной игре).

> — Почему Thermal Expansion теперь подписывается как Thermal?.
> — Это неправильно. На кого подписался?
> — У этого слово не один смысл.
> — Подписаться это поставить подпись, сделать подписку и другое. Вот доказательство:
>
> [image: ссылка на вики-словарь]

Answer (score 1):

В контексте игры предполагается, что игрок постоянно автоматически подписывается под (зачастую, технически, над) своим персонажем и его действиями.

В чатах и форумах это подписывание просходит в еще более прямом смысле: авторство слов подписывается возле каждого сообщения.